# Trying to get property of non object laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've just been tasked with trying to fix an ex-employee's code, and I'm having a hard time. The error I'm receiving is:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: 
/home4/cutcatsc/laravel/resources/views/ballots/show.blade.php)
```

And this is the code I believe to be the issue:

```
                     @extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'View Ballot')

@section('breadcrumbs')
@endsection

@section('content')

    @if($ballot)
    <h2>{{ $ballot->name }}</h2>
    <p>Ballot was created by <a href="{{ url('members/'.$ballot->user_id) }}">{{ $ballot->owner->name }}</a> on <strong>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($ballot->created_at)) }}</strong>.
    <p>This ballot expires on <strong>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($ballot->expiration)) }}</strong>.</p>

    @if($ballot->support()->count() > 0)
        <?php $count = 0 ?>
        <p>This ballot is supported by
        @foreach($ballot->supporters as $supporter)
            <?php $count++; ?>
            <a href="{{ route('members.show', $supporter->id) }}">{{ $supporter->name }}</a>@if($count < $ballot->support()->count()), @endif
        @endforeach
        </p>
    @endif

    @if(Entrust::hasRole('admin') || $ballot->owner->id == Auth::user()->id)
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('ballots.update', $ballot->id), 'class' => 'form', 'id' => 'expirationForm']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        @if($ballot->isExpired())
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Open Ballot</button>
        @else
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="2">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Close Ballot</button>
        @endif
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}

       {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => array('ballots.notify', $ballot->id), 'class' => 'form', 'id' => 'notificationForm']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Send Voting Reminder</button>
    </div>
     {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endif

    @foreach($ballot->content as $content)
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <p>{!! nl2br(e($content->text)) !!}</p>
            @if($content->link != null)
            <p>Additional informtion about this ballot can be found <a href="{{ $content->link }}">here</a>.</p>
            @endif
        </div>
    @endforeach

    @if($ballot->status == 0)

    @if($ballot->checkUserSupport(Auth::user()->id))
            <h4>You've already pledged your support for this ballot.</h4>
        @else 
            <h4>This ballot needs more support before it can be voted on. Click <a href="{{ route('ballots.support', $ballot->id) }}">here</a> to add your support.</h4>
        @endif

    @elseif($ballot->status == 2)
        <h4>The voting period for this ballot has ended.</h4>
    @elseif($ballot->checkUserVote(Auth::user()->id))
        <h4>You've already voted on this ballot.</h4>
    @elseif(Entrust::hasRole('inactive'))
        <h4>You are not currently eligible to vote on this ballot.</h4>
    @else 
        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => array('ballots.vote.store', $ballot->id), 'class' => 'form', 'id' => 'voteForm']) !!}
        <h2>Vote</h2>

        @if($ballot->isBallotPrivate())
            <h3>This is a private ballot - your vote will not be visible to any other member of the collective.</h3>
        @endif 

        @foreach($ballot->questions as $question)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{ $question->question }}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- Determine question type -->
          @if($question->type == 0)
            <div class="radio-inline">
                <label>
                    {!! Form::radio('question['. $question->id .'][vote]','0') !!}
                    Widdit
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-inline">
                <label>
                    {!! Form::radio('question['. $question->id .'][vote]','1') !!}
                    Nope
                </lable>
           </div>
           <div class="radio-inline">
                 <label>
                    {!! Form::radio('question['. $question->id .'][vote]','2') !!}
                    Stand Aside
                </label>
          </div>
          @elseif($question->type == 1)
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                   <div class="btn btn-danger disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></div>
                    @for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        {!! Form::radio('question['. $question->id .'][vote]',$i,false,['class' => 'surveyQuestion']) !!} {{ $i }}
                     </label> 
                    @endfor
                    <div class="btn btn-success disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span></div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
               <p class="help-block">Please rate this question on a scale from 1-5, where one is "this sucks" and five is "fuck yeah".</p>

            </div>

          @elseif($question->type == 4)
          <div class="form-group">
             <p class="help-block">Enter your thoughts in the text area below.</p>


          @else
          <div class="form-group">
             <p class="help-block">Please choose the option you most prefer out of the choices given.</p>
            @foreach($question->choices as $choice)
                <div class="radio">
                     <label>
                        {!! Form::radio('question['. $question->id .'][vote]',$choice->id) !!}
                        {{ $choice->name }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            @endforeach

          </div>
          @endif

          <!-- All questions have a comment area --> 
          <div class="radio-inline">
                <label>
                {!! Form::textarea('question['. $question->id .'][comments]', '', ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Comments?', 'rows' => 2, 'cols' => 110 ]) !!}
                </label>
          </div>
          {!! Form::hidden('question['. $question->id .'][question_id]', $question->id) !!}
          </div>
      </div>
          @endforeach

          <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Vote', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
           </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endif

   @if($ballot->status > 0)
   <h2>Current Votes 
        <small>
            TOTAL <span class="badge">{!! $total = $ballot->votes->groupBy('user_id')->count() !!}</span>

        </small>
   </h2>



   @if($ballot->isBallotPrivate())
            <h4>This is a private ballot, your votes are not visible to other members.</h4>
   @endif

   @if($ballot->votes->count() > 0)
          @foreach($ballot->questions as $question)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>{{ $question->question }} 

                   @if(!$ballot->isBallotPrivate() OR Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))

                        @if($question->type == 0)
                            <a class="btn btn-success disabled" role="button">
                                Yes <span class="badge">{{ $question->votes()->where('vote',0)->count() }}</span> 
                            </a>
                             <a class="btn btn-danger disabled" role="button">
                                No <span class="badge">{{ $question->votes()->where('vote',1)->count() }}</span>
                             </a>
                             <a class="btn btn-info disabled" role="button">
                                Stand Aside <span class="badge">{{ $question->votes()->where('vote',2)->count() }}</span>
                             </a>
                        @elseif($question->type == 1)
                            @for($i=0; $i <= 5; $i++)
                            <a class="btn btn-info disabled" role="button">
                               {{ $i }} <span class="badge">{{ $question->votes()->where('vote',$i)->count() }}</span>
                            </a>
                            @endfor

                        @else 
                            @foreach($question->choices as $choice)
                            <a class="btn btn-info disabled" role="button">
                               {{ $choice->name }} <span class="badge">{{ $question->votes()->where('vote',$choice->id)->count() }}</span>
                            </a>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif

                    @endif
                        @if(true == false)
                        @if($ballot->isExpired() && $question->passed($total) == true)
                            <span class="text-uppercase text-success">Passed <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></span>
                        @elseif($ballot->isExpired() && $question->passed($total) == false ) 
                            <span class="text-uppercase text-danger">Failed <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                        @endif
                        @endif
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

           <!-- If the ballot is public, or if the ballot is private and the user has voted -->
           @if(!$ballot->isBallotPrivate() || $ballot->isBallotPrivate() && $ballot->checkUserVote(Auth::user()->id) || Auth::user()->hasRole('hr'))
           <br><br>
            <table class="table table-striped ballot-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Member 
                        @if(!$ballot->isBallotPrivate()) Name @else Class @endif </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Comment</td>
                </tr>


                     @foreach($ballot->votes as $vote)

                            @if($vote->question_id == $question->id && !$ballot->isBallotPrivate() 
                            || $vote->question_id == $question->id && $ballot->isBallotPrivate() && $vote->user_id == Auth::user()->id 
                            || $vote->question_id == $question->id && Auth::user()->hasRole('hr'))
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                @if(!$ballot->isBallotPrivate())

                                           //@if($vote->user)
                                           <a href="{{ url('members/'.$vote->user_id) }}">  {{ $vote->user->name }}  </a>
                                           //@else 
                                           // User Deleted
                                           //@endif
                                @endif

@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('hr'))
                                    @foreach($vote->user->roles as $role)
                                        <span class="label label-info">{{ $role->name }}</span>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif

                                </td>

                                    <td>{{ $question->showVote($vote->vote) }}</td>

                                <td>{{ $vote->comments }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif

                     @endforeach 
                   </table>
               @endif
               @endforeach
   @else
    <p>No one has voted on this ballot.</p>
   @endif
   @endif

        @if(Entrust::hasRole('admin'))
        <h2>Members who still need to vote</h2>
            <!-- List of users who haven't voted yet - we can use this to vote for users, or check who needs to vote. -->
            <table class="table table-striped ballot-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Member Name</td>
                           <!-- <td>Vote</td> -->
                        </tr>

             </table>
        @endif

    @endif <!-- end if the ballot is live or expired --> 

<!-- 
  <div id="dialog-form" title="Vote for member">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

       Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
-->
@endsection

@section('script')

@endsection
```

Which is the block that ends at line 260.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

For context this error only appears on certain ballot shows. Many of the new ones receive no error, while many of the older ones do.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Honestly I am just very new to PHP and I'm having a hard time with the error message/parsing the show page. For some additional context, this is ballot show page most of the newer ballot views are fine, but many of the older ones receive this error.

Comment: The error is occuring on 260, which is the @endforeach

Comment: Whoops, the last @endforeach

Comment: If it helps I can post the entire page.

Comment: Can you show whole blade??

Comment: Yes, let me edit.

Comment: dump one `$vote` object and see.

Answer (score 0):

All time when use `$ballot->owner` must be check it is not empty

```
@if(!empty($ballot->owner))
    // some code similar this $ballot->owner->id
@endif 

@if (Auth::check()) 
    // The user is logged in... Auth::user()

@endif


@if (!empty($vote->user)) 
    // The user is logged in... $vote->user->roles
@endif
```

Aso used `<td>{{ $vote->comments }}</td>` line 259 it must be changed. `$vote->comments` It must be instane of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. After this correction if there has error you must be in different part `debug code` using `dd() or die` function and get the reason of error. and after it fix error

Comment: @lylesconstant ask me about result